# How can I make a 2-level navigation bar?

Tags: html, css

I am wanting to make a navigation bar just like the one over at http://cryengine.com/ but I dont know how.

HTML:

```
    <div class="navigation">
        <ul id="main-navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Other</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="dev-navigation">
            <li><a href="#">Developer Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Admin Panel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Thanks for youe help. I didnt post any CSS becuase well i dont have any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want sample like this?

See my [**CodePen Link**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zbqvpr)

```css
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  text-align: right;
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  background-color: #303030;
}
#main-navigation,
#dev-navigation {
  height: 40px;
  margin: auto;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 1400px;
}
#main-navigation {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
#dev-navigation {
  width: 70%;
}
ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
  margin: 10px;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <ul id="main-navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Store</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Other</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul id="dev-navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Developer Login</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Admin Panel</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sign up</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That is what im after but "other" is cut off. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by "other" ?

Comment: Ive fixed it. Thank you for your help ;D

Answer (score 0):

```css
.navigation {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: black;
}
#dev {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  height: 48px;
}
ul#dev-navigation {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-right: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
}
#dev-navigation li {
  padding: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
}
ul#main-navigation {
  float: right;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 14px;
}
#main-navigation li {
  padding: 6px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation">
  <div id="dev">
    <ul id="dev-navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Developer Login</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Admin Panel</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="main">
    <ul id="main-navigation">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Forum</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Store</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Other</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Theres a gap of around 1 pixel on the right after "admin panel". Hoe can I fix this?

Comment: that is because of border-right. Add another style                                 #dev-navigation li:nth-child(2){border-right:none;}